# Image invisible in wordpress site after migration with same domain name

Tags: wordpress

I have recently transferred my wordpress site to hostgator. I have only changed the hosting, the domain name is still the same. After transferring my site all the images in the site are invisible even if i upload any new image its is not showing on site.

I have tried to upload the "UPLOAD" folder again and also changed the permissions but the result is still the same.

Please help me as this is a critical issue for me.

My site URL is www.animationcoursesahmedabad.com

Answer (score 0):

define('WP_HOME','http://animationcoursesahmedabad.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://animationcoursesahmedabad.com');

Put this in wp-config.php at root

Comment: this is already set. I have only changed my hosting provider not the domain name

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of javascript errors. That may be the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss @Alan's answer; looking at your blog section I can see the data attributes you're using for lazy loading the images. Those paths resolve just fine, it's the JS that loads the image itself that is failing. The issue you have with uploading sounds like a separate problem altogether.